# chronologic clustering plot with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I need to create this king of graph with ggplot2, I tried a lot of thing with geom_bar, geom_histogram without any success.
Any advice ?

Regards

[image]

```
dataset <- data.frame(
      day=seq(from=as.Date("2010-01-01"), to=as.Date("2010-03-01"), by = 1),
      cluster=factor(sample(x=1:3,size = 60,replace = TRUE))
    )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for `geom_rect`, and as usual in `ggplot2` problems, it is a 
data manipulation problem in disguise. You want to make a data frame you can feed into `geom_rect` so you need `xmin`, `xmax` ...

I'm making some assumptions here based on the sample data you use, you may need to adapt it to the real data you have.

```
dataset %>% 
  mutate( step = cumsum( lag(cluster, 1, default = TRUE) != cluster )) %>% 
  group_by(step) %>% 
  summarise( cluster = first(cluster), date_min = min(day) ) %>%
  mutate( date_max = lag(date_min, 1)) %>% 
  select( -step ) %>% 
  ggplot() + geom_rect( aes(xmin=date_min, xmax = date_max, ymin=0, ymax=1, fill = cluster, col = cluster) )
```

The key is the `step` variable that increments each time you change the `cluster` column:

```
dataset %>% 
  mutate( step = cumsum( lag(cluster, 1, default = TRUE) != cluster )) %>% 
  head
         day cluster step
1 2010-01-01       1    0
2 2010-01-02       3    1
3 2010-01-03       3    1
4 2010-01-04       2    2
5 2010-01-05       3    3
6 2010-01-06       2    4
```

Then you `group_by` this `step` variable. The rest is classic dplyr, then `ggplot2`.

I get this, which is what I understand you want. The rest is just cosmetics.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You could also use `geom_tile` and not transform your dataset:

```
ggplot(dataset) + geom_tile(aes(x=day, y = 1,fill=cluster)) + expand_limits(y=c(-2,4)) + 
  theme(axis.title.y=element_blank(),
  axis.text.y=element_blank())
```

[image]

To change the thickness of the bar, you can vary the `expand_limits()`.

Comment: Great. I always forget about geom_tile :-)

Comment: @RomainFrancois, thanks! Although in cases with a lot of data I feel like your solution is more preferable since instead of plotting a value for each day as in the `geom_tile`, it combines consecutive groups  -
 probably makes rendering better in something like a pdf since less stuff being added to the plot.